Graylog : None of the TrustManagers trust this certificate chain
I'm new to graylog and I have a problem when parting certificates for the server.
When I go to the graylog web interface, I can log in. But in the "Node" part, I find me a debian but it says "System information is currently unavailable.".
When I go to the logs of the graylog it is then written:
2024-06-05T06:10:25.244+02:00 WARN \[ProxiedResource\] Failed to call API on node \<b214f3a2-4662-46ef-a649-aaba691dc433\>, cause: None of the TrustManagers trust this certificate chain. (duration: 21 ms)

I'm using the graylog forum for my installation of Graylog on my debian:
https://go2docs.graylog.org/current/setting_up_greylog/https.html?tocpath=Setting%20up%20Graylog%7CSecuring%20Graylog%7C_____2
And I use a Self-Signed Private Key/Certificate, which I added to the JVM Trust Store
I tried to add the certificate to the trust stores of all my java user@debian versions:
~$ sudo ls /lib/jvm/ 
java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64 java-17-openjadk-amd64 openjdk-17

